# Stop processing inside promise.then

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

So, I started my nodejs journey. I have experience from other languages but promises concepts is quite new to me.

My nodejs environment is expressjs + sequelize.
I'm creating a basic register flow, but I'm stuck at a basic question: how to stop processing inside `then`

```
router.post('/new', function(req, res, next) {
    /* some code here */
    db.user
      .findOne({email: req.body.email})
      .then(user =>{
          console.log(user);
          if(user){
            console.log('Info: Email "'+req.body.email+'" already exists.');
            res.json( {
              meta:{
                success: false,
                message: 'Email "'+req.body.email+'" already exists.',
              }
            });
            return; // <------ 
          }
        })
      .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
        return; // <------ 
      });

    db.user.create({ /* ... */});
});
```

Basically what I want is stop processing when the user already exists. I (think) know that I can move the create inside the findOne, but It feel wrong.

```
router.post('/new', function(req, res, next) {
db.user
      .findOne({email: req.body.email})
      .then(user =>{
          if(user){
            console.log('Info: Email "'+req.body.email+'" already exists.');
            res.json( {
              meta:{
                success: false,
                message: 'Email "'+req.body.email+'" already exists.',
              }
            });
          } else {
              db.user.create({ /* ... */});
          }
        })
      .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
        return; // <------ this is too
      });
    /* no code here */
});
```

thanks

Comment: Use the `next()` callback.

Comment: @marekful it doesn't stop, because i'm getting duplicate error on insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all unsuccessful(warning/error) responses must be catched, its why there is `.catch`. Errors can be catched selectively. It is about personal approach so here is how I would solve this:

```js
// fake db call; set userReturned if user should be returned; userReturned=string
function dbUserCall(userReturned) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, userReturned));
}

// custom error type
function UserExistErr(user) {
  this.msg = 'User ' + user + ' already exists';
  this.user = user;
}

// returns always promise
function createUser(user) {
  if (user)
    return Promise.reject(new UserExistErr(user));
    
  console.log('Info: User does not exist. Creating new one..');
  return dbUserCall('John');
}

function catchRespErr(err) {
  switch (err.constructor) {
    case UserExistErr:
      console.log('Warning: ' + err.msg);
      // set warning res
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
      // set default error res
  }
}

dbUserCall('Jack')
  .then(createUser)
  .then(user => console.log('Info: User '+ user +' created!'))
  .catch(catchRespErr);
```